# cocoon :has_many :through relationship - create new - not just "add existing"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form, has-many-through, cocoon-gem

I am working on a recipe application where a recipe has a title, description, instructions and ingredients with quantities

I'm having a recipe model, a quantity model and an ingredient model:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, 
    :instructions, 
    :title, 
    :quantities_attributes, 
    :ingredients_attributes

  has_many :quantities
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :quantities

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantities,
    :reject_if => :all_blank,
    :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end

class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, 
    :ingredient_id,
    :ingredient_attributes

  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient,
    :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, 
    :ingredient_id

  has_many :quantities
  has_many :recipes, through: :quantities
end
```

I am using cocoon with simple form to create a nested-model-form, here's what I have so far:

recipes/_form.html.haml

```
= f.simple_fields_for :quantities do |q|
    = render 'quantity_fields', :f => q
        = link_to_add_association 'add ingredient', f, :quantities
= f.submit
```

recipes/_quantity_fields.html.haml

```
    = f.input :amount
    = f.association :ingredient, :collection => Ingredient.all(:order => 'name'), :prompt => 'Choose an existing ingredient'
    = link_to_remove_association "remove ingredient", f
```

recipes/_ingredient_fields.html.haml

```
= f.input :name, :hint => 'New Ingredient'
```

here's what I get when adding a new ingredient to my recipe: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/3790e23d-5699-4683-8404-120515affba1/858deb9a56112d179c37d39e61ba0f6d

Now I'm wondering how I could add a completely new ingredient which hasn't been added before - do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just had to add the link_to_add_association tag

recipes/_quantity_fields.html.haml

```
.nested-fields
    = f.input :amount
    = f.association :ingredient, :collection => Ingredient.all(:order => 'name'), :prompt => 'Choose an existing ingredient'
    = link_to_remove_association "remove ingredient", f
    %br
    = link_to_add_association 'or create a new ingredient', f, :ingredient
```